# Simple JQuery question - how do you add value to the title attribute?

Tags: jquery, attributes

Stupid question time - how do you update the title attribute of a control?  Obviously this does not work:

```
$("#valPageIndex").attr('title') = pageIndex;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#valPageIndex").attr('title', pageIndex);
```

Basically, `$("#valPageIndex").attr('title')` is just for getting its value, while `$("#valPageIndex").attr('title', value)` is for setting it.

Here's the official doc: http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#valPageIndex").attr({'title': pageIndex});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#valPageIndex").attr('title', pageIndex);
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#keyvalue

A common jQuery convention is to have `.foo()` or `.foo('selector')` act as a getter and `.foo(value)` or `.foo('selector', value)` act as a setter.